# Excel VBA Multi Column Listbox wrapping to next row when only one record returned

Tags: excel, vba

Thank you in advance for taking the time to help me.  This is my first time asking a question on here - as I have so much success researching existing questions and answers!  I'm a huge fan of this site!

Anyway - to the point.  I've written a program including some list boxes used in a user form. I'm populating these multi-column list boxes from an array that is derived from a SQL statement querying an Oracle database.  When a record in the query results meets certain criteria, that record is published for the end-user in a listbox.

The problem:  when only one record from the query satisfies the criteria, the columns are wrapped into multiple rows instead of on one row.  This causes a problem with what I intend to happen when the user clicks on a row.  I need ALL columns associated with a single record from the query to be written to only ONE row of the listbox - even when there is only one record.  The funny part:  it publishes to the listbox just fine when there are 2 or more records returned.

I appreciate any help!  I've exhausted my online searches and have found no such common problem yet.

Here is some of my code:

```
        .ConnectionString = strDBConnectWrite 'Connect to database
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient 'Necessary for creating disconnected recordset
        .Open 'Open Connection
    End With


    With oTbl4
        .ActiveConnection = oDB
        .source = strSQL4 'SQL statement above
        .LockType = adLockReadOnly
        .Open
        'Populate the array with the recordset
        oArray4 = .GetRows
        k = .Fields.Count
    End With

    x = oTbl4.RecordCount 'for debugging purposes during development

    'Debug.Print "oTbl4 count" & x




    With frmValidationForm.listAddresses 'listbox to which I want to publish the query results
        .ColumnCount = 8
        .ColumnWidths = "100;0;0;0;0;0;0;0"
        .Clear 'Clears the listbox
        .BoundColumn = 1
        .List = Application.Transpose(oArray4)
        .ListIndex = -1
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
.List = Application.Transpose(oArray4)
```

to this:

```
.Column = oArray4
```

Comment: You are AWESOME!  That fixed it.  Thanks SO MUCH for your help :)